# Find matching data between 2 tables of varying columns in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables of varying columns and I am trying to match data between the 2 and find matching first name and last name.  I keep running into problems where common names are matching in other rows.  See my fiddle for the table structure and my attempt. https://jsfiddle.net/0e3moacu/1/

```
jQuery('#attendee02 tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)').each(function(){
        var row=jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery('#attendee01 tr td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4)').each(function(){
            if(row==jQuery(this).html()) jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just to simplify the code, can we use the class ".edituser" as a selector? in your Dataset sample the name example doesn't use this classname :)

Comment: Yes using the class is fine, I have control over the html.

Comment: hi why you do not use $(":first-child") and $(":last-child") function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done by modifying your jQuery code, and looking for the current element index() then checking for the next() ...

```js
jQuery('#attendee02 tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)').each(function(){
            var row=jQuery(this).html();
            var next=jQuery(this).next().html();
            jQuery('#attendee01 tr td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4)').each(function(){
                if(row==jQuery(this).html() && next==jQuery(this).next().html()){
                  jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                    jQuery(this).next().css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                } 
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="attendee01" class="table01">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Org</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Reg Status Details</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td> Health</td>
      <td class="edituser" >Andy</td>
      <td class="edituser">Tom</td>
      <td>SVP</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">15080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Northern</td>
      <td class="edituser" >John</td>
      <td class="edituser">Brd</td>
      <td>VP</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">680</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td> Life </td>
      <td class="edituser">Brean</td>
      <td class="edituser">Lghman</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">462</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>John</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>John</td>
      <td> Travolta</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr> 
    
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Maria</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Cindy</td>
      <td> Beiss</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Alan</td>
      <td> Hendel</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>    

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<table id="attendee02" style="display:non">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th> FName</th>
      <th> LName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>  System</td>
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td> Beiss</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Institute</td>
      <td>Cindy</td>
      <td> Hendel</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Health </td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>

    </tr>


    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I wasn't sure that you need to color them in both tables, because if it's the case using javascript arrays looks to me simpler and I'm not sure if it's faster in this case.

What's done here is mapping those cells by keeping the same logic used in your jQuery selectors while having the same indexes that jQuery found in the document.

```js
t1=[];
t2=[];

//Mapping all cell values by keeping the same rows indexes
//That we use later for jquery
$('#attendee01 tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var tab1 = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
    t1.push(tab1);
});
$('#attendee02 tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var tab2 = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
    t2.push(tab2);
});

//Nested Loop to look for similar values in two sibling cells
for (var i = 1, length = t1.length; i < length; i++) {          
    for (j=2,lim=t1[i].length; j<lim-4;j++){
            for (var k = 1, lim2 = t2.length; k < lim2; k++) {
                for (var z = 1, lime = t2[k].length; z < lime; z++) {
                        if(t2[k][z]==t1[i][j] && t2[k][z+1]==t1[i][j+1]){
                        //console.log(t2[k][z]);
                        $('#attendee01 tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(' + j + ')').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                        $('#attendee01 tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(' + (j+1) + ')').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                        $('#attendee02 tr:eq(' + k + ') td:eq(' + z + ')').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                        $('#attendee02 tr:eq(' + k + ') td:eq(' + (z+1) + ')').css('background-color', 'lightblue');
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="attendee01" class="table01">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Org</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Reg Status Details</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td> Health</td>
      <td class="edituser" >Andy</td>
      <td class="edituser">Tom</td>
      <td>SVP</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">15080</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Northern</td>
      <td class="edituser" >John</td>
      <td class="edituser">Brd</td>
      <td>VP</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">680</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td> Life </td>
      <td class="edituser">Brean</td>
      <td class="edituser">Lghman</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">462</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>John</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>John</td>
      <td> Travolta</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr> 
    
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Maria</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Cindy</td>
      <td> Beiss</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td>Health</td>
       <td>Alan</td>
      <td> Hendel</td>
      <td>CIO</td>
      <td class="nowrap status"></td>
      <td class="notes"> </td>
      <td class="edituser_id" style="display:none;">369</td>
    </tr>    

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<table id="attendee02" style="display:non">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th> FName</th>
      <th> LName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>  System</td>
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td> Beiss</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Institute</td>
      <td>Cindy</td>
      <td> Hendel</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Health </td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td> Thompson</td>

    </tr>


    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very good! I used your first code; I didn't need both tables in blue.  Much appreciated, I struggled with that for a full day.

Comment: Glad it helped ! I added some confusing names to my answer to test for eventual anomalies...